# Am I incorporating this nested Function properly on OpenModelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica, jmodelica

NOTE: This question is referencing PrescribedSpeedPump.mo located ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedSpeedPump

I'm trying to *simple* pump model since all models I build incorporating this pump always yield the same error message:

[1] 16:02:01 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.PowerPlants: 2071:95-2071:108]: Variable q_nom not found in scope ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.

[2] 16:02:01 Translation Error
[ThermoPower.PowerPlants: 2076:84-2076:132]: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope : {q_nom}, {head_nom} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).

Upon inspection of this PrescribedSpeedPump, its composed of two classes: A "FluidMedium" & "flowCharacteristic". It is the Function - "FlowCharacteristic" that is resulting in the error.

Why I am confused:
The error says that it cannot find Variable q_nom within the path of ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components. Well, mentioned earlier, I said this was located within the Examples package of the ThermoPower Library.

Another reason I am confused about this situation, is that I am able to manually enter in parameter values for both q_nom and head_nom. They have been given dummy values of {1,2,3} for both of them. Still, the variable "cannot be found".

Finally, I've tried manually editing the "flowCharacteristic" function myself and then trying to check my model. Still the same error appears. I really do not know how to troubleshoot this error at this point and have tried what I can manage to think of.

If you have any insight or suggestions, please feel free to leave a comment below! Thank you for reading this far, I appreciate your time and effort in trying to help others within this community. Below I have copied the code to my pump model.

CODE UPDATED:

```
model Pump_Verified


function flowCharacteristic =
ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (
q_nom = q_nom, head_nom = head_nom);

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.PrescribedSpeedPump
prescribedSpeedPump1(
redeclare package WaterMedium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater,
Np0 = 1,
V = 20,
head_nom = {1, 2, 3},
hstart = 451024,
n0 = 1200,
nominalFlow = 142.512,
nominalInletPressure=132000,
nominalOutletPressure=8581000,
q_nom = {1, 2, 3},
rho0=1000)
          annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, 0}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedPressureCondenser
Condenser(
Vtot = 50,
p = 132000)  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 40}, extent = 
{{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.SteamTurbineGroup.Components.StateReader_water
stateReader_water1 annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 70}, extent = 
{{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.SteamTurbineGroup.Components.StateReader_water
stateReader_water2 annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 10}, extent = 
{{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Water.SourceMassFlow SourceSteamFlow(
T = 380.561 - 273,
h = 931235,
p0 = 1.32e5,
w0 = 142.512)  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 84}, extent = 
{{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkMassFlow SinkWaterFlow annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {52, 0}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

inner ThermoPower.System system annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 88}, extent = 
{{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensP sensP_Inlet annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-32, 4}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SensP sensP_Outlet annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {26, 4}, extent = {{-10, 
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k = 1200)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, 66}, extent = 
{{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
connect(const.y, prescribedSpeedPump1.pumpSpeed_rpm) annotation(
Line(points = {{2, 66}, {10, 66}, {10, 30}, {-18, 30}, {-18, 6}, {-6, 6}, 
{-6, 6}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(sensP_Outlet.flange, SinkWaterFlow.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{26, 0}, {42, 0}, {42, 0}, {42, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(prescribedSpeedPump1.outlet, sensP_Outlet.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{12, 0}, {26, 0}, {26, 0}, {26, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(sensP_Inlet.flange, prescribedSpeedPump1.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-32, 0}, {-8, 0}, {-8, 0}, {-8, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 
255}));
connect(stateReader_water2.outlet, sensP_Inlet.flange) annotation(
Line(points = {{-50, 4}, {-50, 4}, {-50, 0}, {-32, 0}, {-32, 0}}, color = 
{0, 0, 255}));
connect(Condenser.waterOut, stateReader_water2.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-50, 30}, {-50, 16}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(stateReader_water1.outlet, Condenser.steamIn) annotation(
Line(points = {{-50, 64}, {-50, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(SourceSteamFlow.flange, stateReader_water1.inlet) annotation(
Line(points = {{-62, 84}, {-50, 84}, {-50, 76}, {-50, 76}, {-50, 76}}, 
color = {0, 0, 255}));
annotation (
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version="3.2.2")));

end Pump_Verified;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.PrescribedSpeedPump, but it almost seems as though you want to modify it, in particular:

- The function flowCharacteristic already exist in that model - but is
  not replaceable so you cannot change it, and you could anyway not
  use q_nom from the model in a redeclaration. But since it is already quadratic there is no need to change it.
- The media isn't specified for this component
  (assuming I used the correct ThermoPower version).
- The prescribedspeedpump has an unconnected input.

If you just want to use it:

- Remove the function flowCharacteristic
- Redeclare medium
- Connect some signal to the pump

The following works at least in Dymola:

```
model Pump_Check

function flowCharacteristic =
ThermoPower.Functions.PumpCharacteristics.quadraticFlow (
q_nom = q_nom, head_nom = head_nom);

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.HRSG.Components.PrescribedSpeedPump
prescribedSpeedPump1(
    redeclare package WaterMedium = ThermoPower.Water.StandardWater,
Np0 = 1,
V = 20,
head_nom = {1, 2, 3},
hstart = 451024,
n0 = 1200,
nominalFlow = 142.512,
    nominalInletPressure=132000,
    nominalOutletPressure=8581000,
q_nom = {1, 2, 3},
    rho0=1000)
              annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, 0}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Examples.RankineCycle.Models.PrescribedPressureCondenser
Condenser(
Vtot = 50,
p = 132000)  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 40}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.SteamTurbineGroup.Components.StateReader_water
stateReader_water1 annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 70}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.PowerPlants.SteamTurbineGroup.Components.StateReader_water
stateReader_water2 annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, 10}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));

ThermoPower.Water.SourceMassFlow SourceSteamFlow(
T = 380.561 - 273,
h = 931235,
p0 = 1.32e5,
w0 = 142.512)  annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 84}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

ThermoPower.Water.SinkMassFlow SinkWaterFlow annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {52, 0}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
inner ThermoPower.System system annotation (
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 88}, extent = {{-10,
-10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput pumpSpeed_rpm1
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-46,66},{-6,106}})));
equation 
connect(prescribedSpeedPump1.outlet, SinkWaterFlow.flange) annotation (
Line(points = {{12, 0}, {42, 0}, {42, 0}, {42, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
connect(stateReader_water2.outlet, prescribedSpeedPump1.inlet) annotation (
Line(points = {{-50, 4}, {-50, 4}, {-50, 0}, {-8, 0}, {-8, 0}}, color = {0,
0, 255}));
connect(Condenser.waterOut, stateReader_water2.inlet) annotation (
Line(points={{-50,30},{-50,16}},                            color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(stateReader_water1.outlet, Condenser.steamIn) annotation (
Line(points={{-50,64},{-50,50}},                            color = {0, 0,
255}));
connect(SourceSteamFlow.flange, stateReader_water1.inlet) annotation (
Line(points = {{-62, 84}, {-50, 84}, {-50, 76}, {-50, 76}, {-50, 76}}, color=
  {0, 0, 255}));

  connect(prescribedSpeedPump1.pumpSpeed_rpm, pumpSpeed_rpm1) annotation (Line(
        points={{-5.2,6},{-16,6},{-16,86},{-26,86}}, color={0,0,127}));
annotation (
uses(ThermoPower(version = "3.1"), Modelica(version="3.2.2")));
end Pump_Check;
```

Comment: Hey @HansOlsson ,

Just wanted to let you know that the code you supplied did in fact result in a checked model, it instantiates as well as simulates. Thanks!

Although I do still get the same errors as previously mentioned, it finally works which I am grateful for. However, upon simulation, the outlet pressure does not change to the value I assigned and stays constant with respect to inlet pressure. Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue? This was determined by adding "SensP" or pressure sensors at inlet and outlet of the pump.

Let me know what you think! Thanks!

Comment: First the obvious: Did you connect a normal signal - like a ramp - to the pump. I believe that 0 values are used for such inputs, which doesn't work well.

Comment: Initially, I didn't simulate with any normal signal connect. I would just run the simulation off of the code you copied earlier in this thread.

Comment: Initially, I didn't simulate with any normal signal connect. I would just run the simulation off of the code you copied earlier in this thread. That simulation ran even though there was no signal input.

Comment: However, I am confused as how to connect an input signal into the RealInput component. This is because the code you posted above, has the connection between the Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput and the pumpSpeed_rpm of the prescribedSpeedPump is coming from behind the triangle and not the point. 

My first instinct would be to source the RealInput component with a input singnal, where the RealInput component would then feed into the prescribedSpeedPump speed input. Let me know what you think. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my code above to what I am working with.